# Style base64 SVG from style sheet

Tags: css, svg

So I have the following CSS to produce an SVG logo:

```
 background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,xyz.....");
```

Does anyone know how I can change the colour of the icon with CSS inside my style sheet, as opposed to embedded in the SVG tag.

I'm trying to have the same logo on the page multiple times, in different colours, so don't want to have loads multiple versions of the SVG code in my style sheet.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. If you use SVG as an image it's not externally modifiable.

Comment: That's what I thought. Can anyone suggest any alternative solutions?

Comment: It really depends on the logo and how you want to display it, but one option would be to create an image where the area that you want to change color is transparent, then place it over a coloured background element using absolute positioning.

Comment: Why not display the SVG via an `<object>` or `<iframe>` you can adjust it via the DOM then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using it a lot at different sizes it might be worth making a custom icon font.

Then you can style it with css and use em to keep it sized relatively etc.

http://www.font2web.com/ etc will take an SVG.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments: You can't style it with an external CSS if you display your SVG image using the base64 format. The only way is to use the original `<svg>` format where you can see the tags and properties, either inserted directly into your html or loaded from an external file.